# How to run consul via kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, consul

I tried running the pod (https://www.consul.io/docs/platform/k8s/run.html)

It failed with... containers with unready status: [consul]

kubectl create -f consul-pod.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: consul-example
spec:
  containers:
    - name: example
      image: "consul:latest"
      env:
        - name: HOST_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
      command:
        - "/bin/sh"
        - "-ec"
        - |
            export CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR="${HOST_IP}:8500"
            consul kv put hello world
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Do you have `kubectl logs` for the pod?  Is Consul running on port 8500 on every node in the cluster, either outside of Kubernetes or with a manually exposed host port in a DaemonSet?

Comment: Error! Failed writing data: Put http://192.168.0.22:8500/v1/kv/hello: dial tcp 192.168.0.22:8500: connect: connection refused